# how i can send Json object to graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, mutation

i am using graphql with nestjs .(typescript)

mutation syntax error shows.

even if i send single json value

```
  rules: "{ \"==\" : \"[ { \"var\" : \"a.on\" }, true ]\"}"
```

give error :  Expected value of type "JSON",

here is my sample mutation .

```
condition: {
    rules: { 
        "and" : [
            {"<" : [ { "var" : "a.state.temperature" }, 27 ]},
            {"==" : [ { "var" : "b.state.thermostatMode" }, "cooling" ] }
        ] 
    },
    data: {
        a: { source: 'Entity', id: '123' },
        b: { source: 'Entity', id: '345' },
    }
},
```

and is myDTO

Condition :

```
@Expose()
    @IsOptional()
    @ApiProperty({ type: () => RuleConditionInputDto })
    @Field(() => JSON, { nullable: true })
    condition?: RuleConditionInputDto;
```

and **RuleConditionInputDto**

```
@ObjectType('RuleCondition')
export class RuleConditionDto {
    @Expose()
    @IsDefined()
    @ApiProperty()
    @Field(() => GraphQLJSON)
    rules: RulesLogic;

    @Expose()
    @IsDefined()
    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @Field(() => RuleConditionDataDto, { nullable: true })
    data?: RuleConditionDataDto;
}

@InputType('RuleConditionInput')
export class RuleConditionInputDto {
    @Expose()
    @IsDefined()
    @ApiProperty()
    @Field(() => GraphQLJSON)
    rules: RulesLogic;

    @Expose()
    @IsDefined()
    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @Field(() => RuleConditionDataInputDto, { nullable: true })
    data?: RuleConditionDataInputDto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> even if i send single json value
>
> ```
> rules: "{ \"==\" : \"[ { \"var\" : \"a.on\" }, true ]\"}"
> ```

but the value given above is not a JSON value, it is a string. You may have better luck if you give an actual JavaScript object (there isn't such a thing as a "JSON value"), e.g.:

```
rules: { "==" : [ { "var" : "a.on" }, true ]}
```